# Using Azure cache for node.js website

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-caching

I am developing a node.js website which utilizes the Table storage. I am now trying to utilize the azure cache service with my website, but I am not able to find any examples of connecting to the cache via node.js and accessing it. I found [this](http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2013/09/access-windows-azure-cache-service-from.html) link, but I am not sure where to find the access token for the cache. I created the cache through the Azure powershell using the `New-AzureManagedCache` command. How exactly do I connect to the cache and store/retrieve values?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn448831.aspx? After creating the cache through powershell, you should login to the management portal to get the keys.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you try out the new REDIS cache service which is in Preview. You can access it at https://portal.azure.com.